# How to reconnect data source of Excel pivot table slicers

Tags: excel

I have a table in my excel workbook which comes directly from SQL Server. From this table I have added a pivot with slicers etc. 
I have recently added three new columns to the original data table, not in SQL, but manually in Excel. The new columns contain formulas which updates as I refresh the data from the SQL data source.

I would like to add slicers to my already existing sheet with slicers containing the data from the new columns but for some reason, when I select the data from which to create the slicers, the new columns that I have added does not appear in the list of columns that I can select. If I add the slicers directly from the data table, it is not linked with the rest of my slicers from the same data table.

Should I re-connect the data source to the slicers? If so, how do I completely remove the connection and reconnect again. I have graphs (slicers) and a lot more so I don't want to have to re-do all the work.

Can the problem be that I have added three new columns manually?

Please help! :)

Comment: It seems you made a Pivottable out of data and then you aded the columns which are not appearing in Pivottable field list. You can add those columns with clicking on the pivottable and then on the ribbon (excel top menu bar) under pivottable tools on the analyse tab select Change Data Source to include those newly added columns. And you can also create a dynamic named data range or Table so that you dont have to worry later about new columns/rows.

Comment: For Slicer connections https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg1Sc4ZJsYM